# Paperclip Rails url and asset_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, cdn

According to the [Paperclip S3 Docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) one can specify the `:url` option in the config which has four possible values.  There are comments related to this options that say:

> The fourth option for the S3 url is :asset_host, which uses Rails' built-in asset_host settings.
>
> To get the full url from a paperclip'd object, use the image_path helper; this is what image_tag uses to generate the url for an img tag.

These two comments seem in conflict with each other (to me).  If Paperclip can use the `asset_host` settings, it seems almost necessary that it would generate the full url (since the asset_host only specifies the start (host) of that url)

But it then goes on to say you need to use a helper to get the full url??

The reason I ask this is because I want full urls generated for image url serialization (ie if we're returning json with image_urls, we want those served from our CDN).

Right now I've created a helper module that extends `extend ::Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper` to manually generate full urls any time an image_url is being serialized, but it's manual (and someone could possibly forget to do it in the future)

Any thoughts?